# Terminal hangs on startup

Tags: terminal, macports

I am on OSX Lion. After I Control C the building of Atlas under MacPorts Clang I can no longer get it to run. It start taking around 2GB on startup and even does this after a reboot. After killing the terminal the first time an error report was sent to Apple. The second time killing it did not trigger such a request.
What do I need to do to get the terminal to run again in a normal fashion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try deleting Terminal's saved application state. It's in `~/Library/Saved Application State/com.apple.Terminal.savedState`. You can also try deleting Terminal's preferences. Those are in `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Terminal.plist`.

If you don't want to potentially lose the saved state or preferences, you can move them to the desktop before starting Terminal.

In Lion, you can get to `~/Library` by holding the Option key while selecting the Go menu in Finder.

Comment: I removed `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Terminal.plist` and restarted. The terminal does open now. It still uses 815.8 MB memory and 5 threads while I only have one window opened and am not running any commands. But perhaps that is normal?
PS Nice trick with the options or alt key and Go. Did not know!

Comment: 815.8 MB sounds like a lot. Mine is currently only using 19.0 MB (but is using 5 threads). Have you tried removing the saved state?

Comment: I managed to fix it. I closed the terminal. Opened it. Then just closed the window with the saved state - many lines of compiling code were saved running `sudo port -d upgrade outdated` - and then opened a new window. Now it is just using 34 MB :-)

Comment: Mine is running 5 threads too, but is using ±31 MB Intel (64 Bit). That is OK, right?

Comment: That doesn't sound unreasonable.